# Starting Windows service as anything but Administrator gives 'Access denied'

Tags: windows, service, permission-denied

I'm installing a Windows service that I'm developing. It's set to run as the Network Service. When I attempt to start this service, I get a message box telling me that access is denied. However, the Network Service does have access to the executable, and the entire directory it is contained in.

I've also tried starting the service as Local Service and Local System, but I receive the same error with both. I don't receive any error and the service starts as expected if I run it as Administrator (which is also the account I'm logged in to).

I've looked in the event log, but there is only one entry, containing the same information: 'Access is denied.'

I checked procmon to see what it was trying to access, and to my surprise, access is being denied when the service manager tries to open my executable; even though it has full access.

Why is access to the executable denied? Below are screenshots of the executable's permissions, procmon's output when I try to start the service, and the details of the first CreateFile that gave ACCESS DENIED.

[image: Permissions]

[image: Procmon list]

[image: Procmon details]

Comment: The privileges on the .exe are irrelevant, you need to have the privilege to stop and start the service.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm logged in as the actual Administrator account, I hope I have privileges to do this.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't come out as intended; I do have privileges to start the service. The error is occurring when the network service (or any non-Administrator) account tries to open the executable with certain access.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Please try to make it clear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: How is the problem unclear? When I try to start a service as Network Service after installing it and giving the Network Service user full access to the executable, I receive an 'access denied' error. Even though the permissions show sufficient access.

Comment: It's completely unclear as to what is failing. Perhaps the access denied error comes from your service. Perhaps it's the SCM. I don't know. Clearly something is lacking rights. You'll have to gather evidence.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Did you look at my attachments? I can clearly see in procmon that services.exe is receiving 'access denied' when calling CreateFile on my executable with certain permissions. However, as you can see, Network Service has full access to the file it's having access denied to.

Comment: Why are you applying permissions to your executable? You've probably screwed that up. Revert to default inherited permissions and all should be well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The permissions are on the folder, should I set them on something else?

Comment: Don't set them anywhere

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then what do you suggest I do about this 'access denied' error? The first logical step, in my mind, was to ensure the Network Service had full access to the executable.

Comment: Delete that directory and start again. Don't apply any special permissions to folders or files. Just create a directory and put your exe in there. If you have errors then, investigate them. You don't need to secure executables. By the way, why are you running as Administrator? You should not do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I originally applied permissions in an attempt to resolve the error. I just tried again with a brand new folder and a freshly built executable, and received the exact same error and procmon output attached to my post.

Comment: Seems a bit odd. Try starting with a brand new empty service project. Also, why are you running as Administrator?

Comment: Same issue with a brand new service. I'm running as Administrator for no specific reason; it's a habit I picked up while using Vista and fighting with UAC when I was trying to debug/develop.

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic. I'm having issues with deployment of a service I'm developing. There are a ton of questions on the same topic that aren't closed and have no close votes; many are even the same question with slightly different circumstances.

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?  Please post the output from `icacls`.  Also: is it possible that another process has the file open?  Is it possible that your anti-virus software is blocking access?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: The executable was actually encrypted! Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Please explain why you deleted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872580/why-is-my-custom-marshaller-not-being-invoked-for-return-types

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: My question was incorrect; the DLL function's signature wasn't what I thought it was, which invalidated the entire question. I can undelete it, if you think it has value.

Comment: I just felt irritated that I spent time and effort and you could not even acknowledge that. Seems ungrateful. In any case, my answer would have led you to the solution. Obviously you got there yourself but that's hardly the point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I apologize; I didn't see your response. I always appreciate the time you take to help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was actually that the service executable was encrypted with EFS; the error code (access denied) threw me off.

The service was being output to a folder that was inadvertently encrypted, so when I copied the service out to the install location, it remained encrypted. Once I unchecked the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' check box in the file's properties, the service correctly started for all users.

This explains why the service would only start as the current user, and not any of the system users, including the privileged 'Local System' account.